# Adding repeating date column to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and I am struggling adding dates to my pandas dataFrame df that comes from .csv file. I have a dataFrame with several unique ids, and each id has 120 months, I need to add a column date. Each id should have exactly the same dates for 120 periods. I am struggling to add them as after first id there is another id and the dates should start over again. my data in csv file looks like this:

```
month       id   
  1         1593
  2         1593
 ...
 120        1593
  1         8964
  2         8964
 ...
 120        8964
 1          58944
 ...
```

Here is my code and I am not really sure how should I use groupby method to add dates for my dataframe based on id:

```py
group=df.groupby('id')
group['date']=pd.date_range(start='2020/6/1', periods=120, freq='MS').shift(14,freq='D')
```

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many sets of 120 you have, you can use this. Just change the 2 at the end. This example creates a repeating 120 dates twice. You may have to adapt for your specific use.

```
new_dates = list(pd.date_range(start='2020/6/1', periods=120, freq='MS').shift(14,freq='D'))*2

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': new_dates})
```

Comment: I don't think it will work, because the sets of 120 periods changes it might be 100 or 5000

Comment: you make that a variable like df.shape[0]/120 or something similar

Answer (score 0):

These are the same except ones using lambda

```
def repeatingDates(numIds): return [d.strftime(
    '%Y/%m/%d') for d in pandas.date_range(start='2020/6/1', periods=120, freq='MS')] * numIds


repeatingDates = lambda numIds: [d.strftime(
    '%Y/%m/%d') for d in pandas.date_range(start='2020/6/1', periods=120, freq='MS')] * numIds
```

Comment: Is it possible to write this function as lambda function?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Generally lambda functions are used as arguments in higher order functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas `transform`. This is how I solved it:

```py
dataf['dates'] = \
    (dataf
      .groupby("id")
      .transform(lambda d: pd.date_range(start='2020/6/1', periods=d.max(), freq='MS').shift(14,freq='D')
)
```

Results:

```sh
   month     id      dates
0      1   1593 2020-06-15
1      2   1593 2020-07-15
2      3   1593 2020-08-15
3      1   8964 2020-06-15
4      2   8964 2020-07-15
5      1  58944 2020-06-15
6      2  58944 2020-07-15
7      3  58944 2020-08-15
8      4  58944 2020-09-15
```

Test data:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
month,id
  1,1593
  2,1593
 3,1593
  1,8964
  2,8964
 1,58944
 2,58944
 3,58944
 4,58944""")).astype(int)
```